# Pass parameter into function

Tags: sql, powershell, sccm

I'm trying to pass each value in an array through a function. This is what I have:

```
#Pulls a list of computers from SCCM
$sccmComputers = Get-ComputersCollection -CollectionName "All Desktops" 

#Function to check each item in $sccmComputers against a database.
Function CheckDisposal ($pc){
$check = invoke-sqlcmd2 -ServerInstance shopserv-lr -Database inventory -query "SELECT * FROM Computers WHERE ServiceTag = '$pc' and Status = 'Disposed' "
return $check}

foreach ($pc in $sccmComputers)
{

}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get each of the items from $sccmComputers to pass through the function and if returns true output the value to the console.

**Below is the code that worked for me:**

```
Function CheckDisposal ($a){
$check = invoke-sqlcmd2 -ServerInstance shopserv-lr -Database inventory -query "SELECT * FROM Computers WHERE Name = '$a' and Status = 'Disposed'"
return $check
}


$sccmComputers = Get-ComputersCollection -CollectionName "All Desktops"


foreach($item in $sccmComputers)
{

  $dispose = CheckDisposal $item.Name
  if($dispose)
  {
    Write-Output $dispose.Name
  }
}
```

Comment: well, call your function inside foreach loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($pc in $sccmComputers)
{
    CheckDisposal $pc
}
```

Comment: If the query finds $pc in the database how can I get that to output to the console?

Comment: My assumption is that it gets returned when you do Return $check

Comment: What happens currently if you run your code with the modification above?

Comment: Nothing would happen. I ended up figuring out the problem though. I've edited my question with the correct code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: FYI it's perfectly valid to submit an answer to your own question and accept it :).